# Can you change the TCP congestion control algorithm?

Tags: android, tcp, congestion-control

From an Android app, can you change the TCP congestion control algorithm? Are there functions in the Android API to get and set the TCP congestion control algorithm? In Linux, you can read or write to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control` to get or set the algorithm. Does such a thing exist in Android?

Comment: If your phone is rooted you may be able to.  See this post https://www.speedguide.net/faq/how-to-tweak-android-and-ios-tcpip-settings-496 But in general, I don't think you can.